# Google Maps not loading completely

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

This question may be copy of any other question. But I was unable to find an solution.

I add a Google Map on my page, using jQuery gmap3 plugin. It was working but when I try to show map, it only shows marker and controls. I try using resize but it not working for me. It is looking like this: [image]

Here is my code:

```
savedGpsData = $('#inputGps').val().split(", ");

$("#mapsAddress").gmap3({
    map: {
        options: {
            center: [parseFloat(savedGpsData[0]), parseFloat(savedGpsData[1])],
            zoom: 14
        }
    },
    marker: {
        values: [
            {latLng: [parseFloat(savedGpsData[0]), parseFloat(savedGpsData[1])]},
        ],
        options: {
            draggable: true
        },
        events: {
            dragend: function(marker) {
                $('#inputGps').val(marker.getPosition().lat() + ', ' + marker.getPosition().lng());
                var gps_coor = $('#inputGps').val();
                var gpsLoc = gps_coor.split(', ');
                $('#gps_latitude').val(gpsLoc[0]);
                $('#gps_longitude').val(gpsLoc[1]);
            }
        }
    },
    trigger:"resize"
});
```

Comment: @Nikos what's the point of editing a question and adding English mistakes and wrong punctuation?

Comment: @MrUpsidown: I only corrected the indentation. Where did you see the mistakes from my edit? - Now I see: Obviously there was another pending, unaccepted edit which got overwritten by mine. Please judge more carefully though.

Comment: Right. Sorry about that, I didn't see it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but I think this is the problem, try to reduce the zoom to 9 for example since 14 is too much and that is not showing in the default location any outlines..

try for example zoom : 9

Comment: Could you try to change the default location as the following:  first parameter var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.65914, 0.072050); and then add the center: myLatlng1 to your script

Answer (score 0):

This condition may occurs.  If the value of latitude and longitude is same. So, need to verify this and make sure that this values not be same.